# differential equation of order2

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation

```
ode = x*y''[x] + y'[x] + 4*x^2*(x^2 - 1) y[x] == 0
```

But do not know how to actually solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Change the last `y` to `y[x]` and try feeding it again into `DSolve[]`.

Comment: I obtain answer to form "DifferentialRoot", and I can not obtain y[x].

Comment: and I add conditions: DSolve[ode && y[1] == 0 && y'[1] == 1, y[x], x]

Comment: `DifferentialRoot `actually gives you the symbolic solution of the equation. Inside Mma you may operatre with it as with any regular function, i.e., plot, integrate etc. Have a look in Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I was going to answer as [bbgodfrey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1063/bbgodfrey) did, except I did one little test that stumped me.  It also occurs to me that this ODE might be solvable in terms of hypergeometric functions, but that *Mathematica* either does not find the solution or does not know how to find it.  (This is an area of active research, but it is not my field.  I don't know if anyone on this site will know the answer, but the OP might ask on math.stackexchange.com or mathoverflow.com)

#### Normal `DifferentialRoot` usage

Normally [`DifferentialRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferentialRoot.html) works just like a function, including evaluating it and its derivatives.  For instance:

```
f = DifferentialRoot[
  Function[{y, x}, {y'''[x] + 8 y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0, 
    y'[0] == Sin[2 Pi/3], y''[0] == Sin[4 Pi/3]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{f[x], f'[x], f''[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### The OP's case: A bug?

But with the OP's differential equation we seem to run into a **bug**:

```
ode = x*y''[x] + y'[x] + 4*x^2*(x^2 - 1) y[x] == 0;
{ysol} = DSolve[{ode, y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 1}, y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The function `y[x]` evaluates fine:

```
Table[y[x], {x, 1., 4.}] /. ysol
(*  {0., 0.0405724, -0.122343, -0.0857817}  *)
```

However, the derivative at the initial point results in nonsense and remains unevaluated at other values of `x`:

```
y'[1.] /. ysol
(*  ReplaceAll[1.]  *)

y'[2.] /. ysol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems likely that the problem is that the differential equation in the `DifferentialRoot` for `y'[x]` is singular at `x == 1`:

```
 y'[x] /. ysol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Nonetheless, `ReplaceAll[1.]` hardly seems an acceptable return value.

#### Other approaches

One might:

- Use a differential initial point, such as `x == 2`, avoiding `x == 0` and `x == 1`.  Things seem to work better (and faster).
- One can develop (a finite portion of) a Frobenius series at `x == 0`, if local analysis is desired.
- It's possible to use the solution returned by `DSolve` to find another independent solution and to construct the general solution (albeit in terms of the troublesome `DifferentialRoot`).

Example: Initial conditions at `x == 2`:

```
ode = x*y''[x] + y'[x] + 4*x^2*(x^2 - 1) y[x] == 0;
{ysol} = DSolve[{ode, y[2] == C[1], y'[2] == C[2]}, y, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note than the constant `C[1]` was replace by an expression in terms of `C[2]` and a new `C[3]` for some reason.  Now we can find initial conditions at `x == 2` that give `y[1] == 0` and `y'[x] == 1`.  The `DifferentialRoot` in this case is well behaved, even at `x == 1`.  Note also that `DifferentialRoot` requires exact coefficients; hence the `SetPrecision[_, Infinity]`.

```
obj[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := {y[1.], y'[1.]} - {0, 1} /. ysol /.
  {C[3] -> SetPrecision[a, Infinity], C[2] -> SetPrecision[b, Infinity]};
ic0 = FindRoot[obj[a, b], {{a, 1.}, {b, 1.}}] /. {a -> C[3], b -> C[2]}
(*
  {C[3] -> -0.286103, C[2] -> -1.37527}
*)

Plot[{y[x], y'[x]} /. ysol /. SetPrecision[ic0, Infinity] // Evaluate,
 {x, 0.2, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice analysis.  Solving the ODE with conditions `y[1] == 1, y'[1] == 0` gives the same strange `y[x]` results you obtained for `y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 1`.  However, the case I plotted in my answer does not give these strange results.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks.  Yeah, I tried it both ways (ics at x == 1), but it's a long answer already.  Your method avoids trouble by starting close to the singular point, instead on directly on it (which I guess you realize).

Comment: You correctly point out that `y'[x] /. ysol` yields  a `DifferentialRoot` expression that is singular at `x == 1`.  Yet, `x == 1` clearly is an [ordinary point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) of `ode`, and it is straightforward to construct a power series for `y[x]` there (e.g., using `Series[ode[[1]], {x, 1, 3}]`).  It would appear, therefore, that this instance of `DifferentialRoot` is incorrect, reinforcing your observation that a bug exists.

Comment: Dear Michael, can you help me for this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86302/solving-differential-equation-analytical-or-numerical

Answer (score 1):

The point made by Alexei Boulbitch can be illustrated by computing and plotting a solution well behaved near `x = 0`.

```
sol = y /. First@DSolve[ode && y[1/1000] == 1 && y'[1/1000] == 0, y, x];
Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 6}]
```

[image]

The solution decreases both in amplitude and wavelength roughly as `1/x`.  Like any such second order linear ODE, it admits a second solution, singular at `x = 0`.