# Solving differential equation (Analytical or Numerical)

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation for $0 < x < 1$

```
DSolve[y''[x] == (λ x^(3/4) y[x])/Sqrt[1-x], y[x], x]
NSolve[y''[x] == (λ x^(3/4) y[x])/Sqrt[1-x], y[x], x]
```

But do not know how to actually solve it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] == (l x^(3/4) y[x])/Sqrt[1 - x], 
                      y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1/2}, y, {x, 0, 1}, l]

Show@Quiet@Table[Plot[(y /. p)[l][x], {x, 0.1, 1}], {l, 1, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can we have y[x] in terms λ?

Comment: @Bahram I'm solving it numerically. I doubt there is a closed form

Comment: @Bahram You can get things like `Table[Plot[(y /. p)[l][x], {l, 0.1, 1}], {x, .1, .7, .1}]`, though

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, How did you add those BCs ?